# How to invite friends from facebook from my website

Tags: facebook

On my website, I basically want a user to be able to invite his facebook friends.
You know have like an Invite Friends button - when the user clicks on it - FAcebook widget opens up - which will ask for the users' facebook username/password and once he logs in - shows him his list of friends - he can select the friends - and they get a message from him inviting them to join my website.

I am looking at this link:
http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php#Basic

Every tutorial I look at just talks about the SHARE button.
How do I get the user to send an invite message to his facebook friends
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) or the [Friends Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/)?