# Ways to invite friends from facebook to website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, invite

What ways to invite user friends on facebook connected website you know?

During last days I've found following methods:

- Just post message on user wall.
  But it's not targeted message.
- Send facebook messages to friends using [message dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/).

But it can lead app to ban with following reason "Facebook messages is a channel for user-to-user communication, and not for applications to send messages to their users, or encourage users to spam their friends"

- Develop simple canvas app and integrate it with website. After it use [app install requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).

But it can lead app to ban, again, cause of [facebook policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). 
 - "I.11 Apps on Facebook may not integrate, link to, promote, distribute, or redirect to any app on any other competing social platform"

- Also there are a couple of old same questions([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961202/invite-facebook-friends-on-a-website-is-it-possible) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276115/how-to-invite-friends-from-facebook-from-my-website)), that suggests to use fbxml - but it is deprecated by facebook.

So, are there any ways to invite friends from facebook to website directly?

Comment: This doesn't really seem directly related to software development, as much as it is to software marketing strategies. Voting to close.

Comment: It's about software development and facebook api usage. Also, if there are no way to directly invite facebook user to site - that will be answer too. I am, as developer, don't see this question as software marketing question. If you see - that's ok.

Comment: @NikolayFominyh, for facebook 3.2 or above, have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157784/can-we-invite-people-to-use-our-app-or-send-friend-request-from-the-app-via-face/16605625#16605625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no way to do it programmatically in current facebook API version. Only canvas apps can invite friends. Also you can use messaging on your own risk.

Answer (score -2):

If they are you r friends you can add web url to each of their walls. Or via private message.

Comment: Sorry, if they are my friends - I just can send private messages to friends using message dialog. It's in my question.